# How to get grunt task name given on command line?

Tags: gruntjs

In order to customize my grunt tasks, I need access to the grunt task name given on the command line when starting grunt.

The options is no problem, since its well documented (grunt.options).
It's also well documented how to find out the task name, *when running a grunt task*.

But I need access to the task name before.

Eg, the user writes
`grunt build --target=client`

When configuring the grunt job in my `Gruntfile.js`, I can use
`grunt.option('target')` to get `'client'`.

But how do I get hold of parameter `build` before the task build starts?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your grunt file is basically just a function.  Try adding this line to the top:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
/*==> */    console.log(grunt.option('target'));
/*==> */    console.log(grunt.cli.tasks);

// Add your pre task code here...
```

Running with `grunt build --target=client` should give you the output:

```
client
[ 'build' ]
```

At that point, you can run any code you need to before your task is run including setting values with new dependencies.

Comment: This answer is correct now that it has been edited.

To see the task name given from the command line, use: console.log(grunt.cli.tasks); tasks is an array

Answer (score 4):

A better way is to use `grunt.task.current` which has information about the currently running task, including a `name` property. Within a task, the context (i.e. `this`) is the same object. So . . .

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'Foobar all the things', function() {
  console.log(grunt.task.current.name); // foo
  console.log(this.name); // foo
  console.log(this === grunt.task.current); // true
});
```

If `build` is an alias to other tasks and you just want to know what command was typed that led to the current task execution, I typically use `process.argv[2]`. If you examine `process.argv`, you'll see that `argv[0]` is `node` (because `grunt` is a `node` process), `argv[1]` is `grunt`, and `argv[2]` is the actual grunt task (followed by any params in the remainder of `argv`).

EDIT:

Example output from `console.log(grunt.task.current)` on grunt@0.4.5 *from within a task* (can't have a current task from not a current task).

```
{
  nameArgs: 'server:dev',
  name: 'server',
  args: [],
  flags: {},
  async: [Function],
  errorCount: [Getter],
  requires: [Function],
  requiresConfig: [Function],
  options: [Function],
  target: 'dev',
  data: { options: { debugPort: 5858, cwd: 'server' } },
  files: [],
  filesSrc: [Getter]
}
```

Comment: `grunt.task.current` gave me `undefined` with grunt 0.4.5.  Which version are you using?

Comment: 0.4.5. Are you doing that from within a task? Cause if not, then "undefined" makes sense. I'll add my output above (too messy for a comment).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was inside `module.exports = function (grunt) {...`, but outside `grunt.initConfig...`.  It looks like `grunt.task.current` isn't available there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grunt.util.hooker.hook` for this.

Example (part of Gruntfile.coffee):

```
grunt.util.hooker.hook grunt.task, (opt) ->
  if grunt.task.current and grunt.task.current.nameArgs
    console.log "Task to run: " + grunt.task.current.nameArgs
```

**CMD**:

```
C:\some_dir>grunt concat --cmp my_cmp
Task to run: concat
Running "concat:coffee" (concat) task
Task to run: concat:coffee
File "core.coffee" created.

Done, without errors.
```

There is also a hack that I've used to prevent certain task execution:

```
grunt.util.hooker.hook grunt.task, (opt) ->
  if grunt.task.current and grunt.task.current.nameArgs
    console.log "Task to run: " + grunt.task.current.nameArgs
    if grunt.task.current.nameArgs is "<some task you don't want user to run>"
      console.log "Ooooh, not <doing smth> today :("
      exit()  # Not valid. Don't know how to exit :), but will stop grunt anyway
```

**CMD, when allowed**:

```
C:\some_dir>grunt concat:coffee --cmp my_cmp
Running "concat:coffee" (concat) task
Task to run: concat:coffee
File "core.coffee" created.

Done, without errors.
```

**CMD, when prevented**:

```
C:\some_dir>grunt concat:coffee --cmp my_cmp
Running "concat:coffee" (concat) task
Task to run: concat:coffee
Ooooh, not concating today :(
Warning: exit is not defined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```